# Auto/hide header placed below top-image needs to be activated when reaching top of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this auto/hide header, which is placed with absolute position below the top image.

```
   .header-sticky {
        margin: -30px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px 55px;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        z-index:9;
        width: 52.4%;
        right: 0;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Right now it activates an auto/hide function with an offset setting, but I would like to activate this when the header reaches the top of the document.

How can this be done?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dp174zjx/1/

The problem is that I need to activated following classes when the header reaches the top:

```
.header-sticky--hidden {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -100% ) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateY( -100% ) !important;
    transform: translateY( -100% ) !important;
    }

    .header-sticky--narrow {
     position: fixed;
   z-index:9;
   top: 0px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var offset = $('.header-sticky').offset().top;
  if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= offset ) {
      //Hide the header
  }
});
```

Comment: Will this also work with the code I have right now? There is an auto/hide function activated with an offset of 600px. But instead of being activated by the offset I would like it to be activated when it reaches the top of the document

Comment: @DWTBC You got an answer. Go ahead and try it first, then keep asking.

Comment: I did try to paste it in, and couldn't get it to work -> hence my question

Comment: Try doing it now there was a typo.

Comment: I don't know if I am placing the code, the wrong place, but it doesn't seem to work.

It still activates the auto/hide function after 600px (the offset) instead og activating the auto/hide when the header reaches the top